# Deleting rows based on 2 different string values

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way of adding another text value that will remain when a lot of other rows get deleted? Right now in row "I", I need to delete any row that has a value that isn't "200" or "900".

```
Sub macro20()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim x As Long
Set Rng = Range("I1:I" & Range("I65536").End(xlUp).Row)
For x = Rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If InStr(1, Rng.Cells(x, 1).Value, "200") = 0 Then
        Rng.Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next x
End Sub
```

This is what i have so far but i am not aware of how i would go about adding another text value to keep the row from being deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
If Rng.Cells(x, 1).Value <> 200 And Rng.Cells(x, 1).Value <> 900 Then
```

This is for cell values that are true numbers; not for cell values that might contain *200* or *900* as part of a longer text string.

Comment: that works perfectly, thank you :). just a little disappointed that i was stuck on something so simple now :P.